# Can't realize PUT requests with c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

After (early all works ok) setting c3p0 connection pool to PostgreSQL DB like this:

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">500</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
```

can't realize PUT (only) requests. Hibernate works ok, but there are no records in DB. I tried different sets without result. What's wrong?

UPD: as we see in DB: PUT requests comes (they correct) but Hibernate rollback them. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Find solution:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.autoCommitOnClose">true</property>
```

It's works. But i'am not sure in it correction.